# How can I convince Internet Explorer to allow authentication as another user?

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

Thanks for reading and for your thoughts; this is a hairy problem, so I thought I'd share to see if it is actually a fair challenge for more seasoned developers than ourselves.

We're developing a web application for a corporate Microsoft Active Directory environment, and we use Windows Authentication provided by IIS to authenticate users for single-sign-on, alongside Forms Authentication. I know IIS complains when both are enabled, but it works very well, and every site we've deployed at has had no weird quirks to work around - until now.

The new site has "shared" machines, logged in permanently with a generic account that has read-only access to the applications they need to use. This means that we can't differentiate between users who should have different permissions to the application; we need some way of prompting the user for authentication details.

First try was some serious googling; nobody else in the world seemed to have our problem except for a few misguided souls who had asked questions into the ether and received no response.

After a bit of brainstorming and nutting out the way IIS's authentication works, it seemed that the most straightforward way to approach the problem was to issue a `401 Unauthorized` in response to a user known to be a shared account. Initial tests here seemed fruitful, yielding successful changes of username inside the browser, however a prototype at the site did not prompt for credentials, and the browser kept the same account details. We also hit on the IE-specific javascript

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")
```

which, again, worked in the lab but not onsite. Further experiments with IE security settings onsite revealed that the browser would automatically reauthenticate if the webapp site was excluded from the Intranet Zone, regardless of the method used to trick the browser into prompting the user for new account details.

Now we're stuck. We've got workaround options for getting it going on time, but they're definitely not the "right" answers:

- require users to log out of the shared account before logging into our app (...yuck)
- exclude our webapp from Intranet Zone on all machines
- provide a non-SSO login service for users

I'm convinced that there's a canonical way to do this - a known pattern, a common base problem that's already been solved, something like that - and I'm very interested to hear what sort of inventive methods there are to solve this sort of problem, and if anyone else has actually ever experienced anything remotely like it.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to just supply a second shortcut to IE on these machines, with the "Run with different credentials" option turned on? - so launching from that shortcut will prompt for new credentials

Comment: Well have you considered using another browser? FireFox for instance does not know the Single-Sing on feature but pops up a login input form each time you access the page for the first time...

Comment: @Yves M. We're pretty restricted in the target environment; everything's fairly bureaucratic, Microsoft kit, even convincing sites to use a browser version more recent than IE6 is difficult. Changing browser vendor is not an option :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's a great idea, the site has us set up with a desktop shortcut already and it might be trivial to customise it per client. Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned Form authentication alongside with Windows authentication.  When will the users use form to logon your app?

Comment: @Harvey Kwok If Windows Authentication doesn't work then we want to fall back to Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up settling on a solution that submits a query to the LDAP directory the server knows about. It means having to accept the user's password, but no other solution was solid enough to run in a production environment.

Hopefully this helps someone. .NET Framework 3.5+ required.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

private static bool IsLdapAuthenticated(string username, string password)
{
    PrincipalContext context;
    UserPrincipal principal;

    try
    {
        context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        principal = Principal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username) as UserPrincipal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle server failure / user not found / etc
    }

    return context.ValidateCredentials(principal.UserPrincipalName, password);
}
```

Comment: I have done similar thing before.  I also used both Windows authentication and Form authentication.  If Windows Authentication doesn't work, we redirect the user and fall back to use Forms authentication.  I also had similar problem as you are facing now.  The solution I provided was to have the form authentication page provide two logon option.  "Windows authentication" and "Specify another credentials.  This doesn't force the user to always type in the password.  If he likes to use his currently logon credentials, I still allow them to do this and redirect him to the Windows auth page

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create a page to which the shared accounts are denied access. Then do a redirect to that page, with a return URL encoded in the query string, at any point where you need the user to reauthenticate with a non-shared account? This should trigger the browser to put up the usual login dialog.

After the user reauthenticates, the new page should just redirect back to the return URL in the query string.

Comment: Tried that; it's basically the same as the 401 response solution. Because the server is in the Intranet Zone to the browser, it will repeatedly retransmit the same credentials until it reaches a preset limit of failures, and then display a 401 Unauthorized page in the browser.